# JSP with Java beans complex types

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I have a Java bean class with property Jobs which returns complex type jobs. 
I am unable to find how to catch all the jobs at once in JSP file.
Let me show my code below:

My javabean Class:

```
public Jobs[] getMatchingJobs() throws RemoteException {
    JobProviderServiceStub stub = new JobProviderServiceStub();
    ViewMatchingJobs matchingJobs = new ViewMatchingJobs();
    matchingJobs.setSkillcode(skillcode);
    Job[] j = stub.viewMatchingJobs(matchingJobs).get_return();
    return j; 
}
```

Now I am writing something like this in JSP:

```xml
<body>
    <jsp:useBean id="jobs" class="com.cs.javabean.jobsBean">
<p> <jsp:getProperty name="jobs" property="MatchingJobs"/> </p>
```

I even don't know whether I can use the above JSP to get all jobs.
and even if I get I don't know how to display them.

Can somebody help me do that?
Any help could be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the getProperty tag, the 'name' parameter refers to the object whose property you want to get. It's the id specified in the 'useBean' tag.

So change

```
<jsp:getProperty name="students" property="MatchingJobs"/>
```

to

```
<jsp:getProperty name="jobs" property="MatchingJobs"/>
```